# Getting lint error for using file extensions in import

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

When I import using extension as follows, my Node.js app works fine:

```
import router from './utils/route.js';
```

But my lint throws following error:

```
Unexpected use of file extension "js" for "./utils/route.js"
```

I can fix the lint by removing the js extension as follows.

```
import router from './utils/route';
```

But now when I run the app, I get the error:

```
Cannot find module
```

I tried ignoring the rule in my `.eslintrc.json` file but this doesn't work, lint still throws same error.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages"
        ]
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Evidently your lint config doesn't enforce what your actual module resolution needs. `"js": "never"` isn't appropriate if you actually need the extension.